# What is the best practice to search ElasticSearch 6 using wildcard and case insensitive term?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I want to query a field in elasticsearch 6 using wildcard and case insensitive term.

Currently the filed is being saved as keyword.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "myType": {
      "properties": {
        "myObj": {
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

where the normalizer is defined in the settings using

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "normalizer": {
          "lowercase_normalizer": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase"
            ],
            "type": "custom",
            "char_filter": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This allows me to query using

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "metaSite.name3": "Aa*" . //* or "aa*"
    }
  }
}
```

1. Is this the best practice?
2. My field is name. I think I should set it as "test" instead of keyword.
   But then it will be stored as lower case and the search with AA* will not return.

What is the best practice to search ElasticSearch 6 using wildcard and case insensitive term?